# How to do multiple live preview without duplicating codes?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a very simple jQuery live preview method which works brilliantly. But how do I have multiple input without having to duplicate the live preview codes for each input?

What I currently have:

```
$(function() {
    $(".input-1").keyup(function() {
        var word=$(this).val();
        $(".code-1").html(word);
        return false;
    });
});

<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="comments">
        <label for="input-1">Content:</label><input name="input-1" id="input-1"></input>
    </form>
    <h3>Codes:</h3>
    <code><pre>&lt;h2&gt;<span class="code-1"></span>&lt;/h2&gt;</pre></code>   
</div>
```

What I want to achieve (up to 20 inputs):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="comments">
        <label for="input-1">Content:</label><input name="input-1" id="input-1"></input>
        <label for="red">Content:</label><input name="red" id="blue"></input>
        <label for="blue">Content:</label><input name="blue" id="blue"></input>
    </form>
    <h3>Codes:</h3>
    <code><pre>&lt;h2&gt;<span class="input-1"></span>&lt;/h2&gt;
    &lt;h2&gt;<span class="red"></span>&lt;/h2&gt;
    &lt;h2&gt;<span class="blue"></span>&lt;/h2&gt;
    </pre></code>   
</div>
```

Comment: As an aside, the `for` attribute for a `<label>` element should be the `id` of another element, not the `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need a two things:

1. A selector to handle keyup for the elements you care about
2. A way to extract the number of the correct ID given the generic selector in 1.

There are many ways to each of these, for example the first one can be achieved using things like jQuery [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), jQuery [find](http://api.jquery.com/find), while the second one is a simple string manipulating problem that can be solved with JavaScript [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), or JavaScript [String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Here is just one example

```
  $(function() {
        // Find all inputs whose name attribute begins with 'input-'
        $("input[name^='input-']").keyup(function() {
            var word=$(this).val();

            // Split the string using the '-' delimiter, and grab the second token
            var number = $(this).attr("name").split('-')[1];

            // Select element(s) with the class name 'code-' + the number found above
            $(".code-" + number).html(word);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What if the class names arent 'input-1,2,3,etc', rather they have their own names such as 'donkey' 'monkey' etc?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this change, and indicate what else the controls you want to select have in common. For example, do you want to select all the input controls under the form with class = "comments"?

Comment: Sure, changes updated in original post. Nope I dont need to select all the input controls. Thanks for that.

Comment: What do you need to select, then? It looks like you needed to select all of the inputs in the form.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you type something into input.input-1, it should reflect in span.input-1; input.red -> span.red; input.blue -> span.blue. I'm not sure what you mean by select.